# How do I turn JSON into plain old data (Map, List, String, Int etc.) in Scala/Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework, type-conversion

I have a [JsValue](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsValue) corresponding to the following JSON object:

```
{"foo": [{"id": 1, value: "bar"}, {"id": 2, "value": "baz"}, ...]}
```

Is there some easy way to turn this into a `Map(String, List(Map(String, Either(String, Int))))` or some other structure of regular ol' data?

I want to query the JSON for whether `<anonymous outermost value>["foo"]` contains `{"id": 42, "value": "Towel"}`. This would be easy for me if I could convert the JsValue object to plain old collections*. Is there some other straightforward way to do so on JsValue objects?

(*) I think it'd be something like `anonymous_outermost_value("foo") contains Map("id" -> Left(42), "value" -> Right("Towel"))`.

(In this particular application, I would be OK with converting all the IDs to strings and turning the `Either(String, Int)` into just `String`, if that makes stuff easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Work with `Map`, `List` etc is not easier than work with Playframework Json.
If you want use the usual way to work with data, [JSON basics](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson) helps you.

You must implement converters Json <-> Plain objects with Json `Reads[T]` and `Writes[T]`

For example Json object `{"id": 1, value: "bar"}` represented with `case class A(id: Long, value: String)` and `{"foo": [{"id": 1, value: "bar"}..` represented with `case class B(foo: List[A])`. The simplest way for implement converter Json <-> Plain objects is Json.format[T] macros.

```
implicit val aFormat = Json.format[A]
implicit val bFormat = Json.format[A]
```

Then you may use `Json.toJson[T](o: T)` <-> `Json.fromJson[T](json: JsValue)` for converting T <-> JsValue

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the JsValue to a `JsObject` (which is simply a wrapper around a `Map[String, JsValue]`), extracting the `foo` property as a `JsArray` (which is a wrapper around a `Seq[JsValue]`) and so on. But I think it's really easier to simply use the Json functions:

```
for {
  foo <- (json \ "foo").validate[Seq[JsObject]]
  obj <- foo
  id <- (obj \ "id").validate[Int]
  value <- (obj \ "value").validate[String]
  if id == 42 && value == "Towel"
} {
  // do something
}
```